# VS2010 MVC3 - Spark not showing in View Engine dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am in the process of converting a good sized asp.net 4 site to MVC3 and I am having trouble with the helper functions in razor partial views. So I wanted to try Spark but after using NuGet to install Spark in my project I don't see how to create a Spark view.

I am assuming that Razor and Spark will co-exist in the same project? If that is not true, then that is probably my problem.

When I treid to create a new view I expected to see Spark in the View Engine drop down on the Add View dialog. Only razor and aspx show up.

I have restarted vs2010 several times now and I shouldn't need to reboot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jacqueseloff/archive/2010/07/30/mvc-3-supporting-custom-view-engines.aspx).

Comment: I started with that blog post. After your entry I  went back to verify that the ViewEngine.xml file was actually there and it wasn't. Recreated that file, double checked that the file existed and now it works, thanks,